# How can I handle a touch event in cocos2d for Android?

Tags: android, cocos2d

How can I handle a touch event in cocos2d for Android? And how to move a sprite using `ccTouchesMoved`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable touches by adding `this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);` to the constructor of your `CCLayer`. Then override `ccTouchesMoved`, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean ccTouchesMoved(MotionEvent e)
{
    // convert event location to CCPoint
    CCPoint p = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(e.getX(), e.getY());

    // update the position of your sprite
    yourSprite.setPosition(p.x, p.y);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hello bummzack thanks a lot for helping me it is working. Could you also tell me if i want to move the object with box2d body how can i move ?

Comment: @jubin: You could simply set the position of the Box2d body in the `ccTouchesMoved` function. Or implement mouse-picking using the MouseJoint [like in the Box2d testbed](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/jbox2d-testbed/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/testbed/framework/TestbedTest.java#666).

Comment: Thanks for the reply if i want to do this without using mouse joint can i do becoz i don't know how to use the mouse joint. I am new in game development.

Comment: @jubin: If that stuff is too complicated for you, you might want to consider not using a physics-eninge at all and rather implement a simple game without the use of Box2d.

Comment: There is any other mothod for physics engine . I am new in game development.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d

Comment: -1. While this appears to be an excellent tutorial, a link alone is not an answer (what happens if that site goes down?) and also it's about cocos2d for iOS which is different from the android port.